# How to match a negated word in a regex

Tags: html, regex

for better or worse I need to do the following using a regex:

match everything between an opening and closing textarea html tag:

```
Other HTML 
<textarea id = foo class = 'bar'> 

some text which can include brackets> like that 

<thi is an opening bracket > that was a closing one 

</textarea>
Other HTML
```

The regex I've got so far is the following except it doesn't go all the way to the ending textarea

```
<textarea id = foo[^>]+>[^>]+>
```

We're using a proprietary system and we don't have any alternatives. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What's the `id = foo`? Is that an attribute/val that's necessary ?

Comment: Try `(?s)<textarea id = foo[^>]+>.*?</textarea\s*>`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest pattern I can come up with:

```
<textarea[^>]*>(.*?)<\/textarea>
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hY1vE8/1). Use with the `s` option or add `(?s)` in the front of the pattern if your tool allows it. If it doesn't, replace `.` with `[\s\S]` as a workaround.

This makes use of a nongreedy quantifier.

The contents of the tag are captured in the first (and only) group.

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -0777ne 'print $& if /<textarea .*?textarea>/s' file.txt
```

Output:

```
<textarea id = foo class = 'bar'> 

some text which can include brackets> like that 

<thi is an opening bracket > that was a closing one 

</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a RegExp, I would do it with some simple vanilla JavaScript.  Like this:

```js
function getText(){
  
var text1 = document.getElementById('text1').value;
  
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = text1;
  
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text1">Here is text with some &lt;'s and some &gt;s.</textarea><br/>
  
    <button onclick="getText()">Get the text above, store it in variable &quot;text1&quot;, and then display it below.</button><br/><br/>

<p id="output"></p>
```

I know that this isn't what you asked for, but I find it easier, and it's just a suggestion.  I hope it helps!